# Свернуть меню после выбора элемента

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Есть меню, на `jquery`, при нажатии на кнопку оно разворачивается, при нажатии еще раз сворачивается.
Как сделать чтобы оно сворачивалось при выборе элемента меню? Что дописать?

```
$(".menu_button").click(function() {
    $(".nav_bar ul").slideToggle();
});
```

`.menu_button` - это кнопка, `.nav_bar ul` это список элементов.

Все бы ничего, но из меню открывается одно попап окно и после его открытия меню остается раскрытым поверх попап окна. Я конечно могу установить у окна з-индекс побольше, но будет не то все равно.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#nav_menu").slideUp();
$(".nav_bar").click(function() {
  $("#nav_menu").slideToggle(500)
})

$(".menu_button").click(function() {
  $("span").text($(this).text());
  $("#nav_menu").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav_bar">Click me</div>
<ul id="nav_menu">
  <li class="menu_button">111111</li>
  <li class="menu_button">222222</li>
  <li class="menu_button">333333</li>
  <li class="menu_button">444444</li>
</ul>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает